# How to use up and down arrow keys for autocomplete search from database

Tags: jquery, mysql, css, database, autocomplete

I have code for autocomplete search from database. Here when searching is being done as i am typing the letters the related names are displaying from the database just like Google.

The problem is in this search results i am unable to use arrow keys for selection. Please help me any code needs to be added for that.

Thank You!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
     $(".search").keyup(function() 
     { 
        var searchid = $(this).val(); 
        var dataString = 'search='+ searchid; 

        if(searchid!='')
        {
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "search.php",
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          success: function(html)
          {
              $("#result").html(html).show();
          }
       });
     }return false;    
});

jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $('#searchid').val(decoded); 
});

jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
       jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
    }
});

$('#searchid').click(function(){
    jQuery("#result").fadeIn(); 
});
});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hint(string)
{
if(string.length==0)
{
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
}
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","get.php?searchid="+string,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body{ 
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
}
.content{
    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px;
}
#searchid
{
    width:500px;
    border:solid 1px #000;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:14px;
}
#result
{
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    padding:10px;
    display:none;
    margin-top:-1px;
    border-top:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px #CCC solid;
    background-color: white;
}
.show
{
    padding:10px; 

    font-size:15px; 
    height:10px;
}
.show:hover
{
    background:#4c66a4;
    color:#FFF;
    cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form method="GET"  onkeyup="hint(this.value)">
<div class="content">
<p><font face="cambria" color="green" size="6"><b>Search Staff byName</b>
<input type="text"class="search" onkeyup="hint(this.value)id="searchid"> 
<div id="result" align="center">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use **up and down** arrow for **autocomplete**, Try this to get your answer.

```
$(document).on('keyup keydown', '.search', function(){
 var searchid = $(this).val(); 
var dataString = 'search='+ searchid; 
if(searchid!='')
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "search.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$("#result").html(html).show();
}
});
}return false;    
});
```